# Databind a button click in a reusable Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, prism

I'm using Mvvm/Prism to design an interface , i created a user control with code behind that have label textbox boutton (nothing mvvm)

the whole project is on mvvm pattern and i have a page Home that contains 3 of that user control.

In my userControl i databind the label content to a property (string)PROP1 the textbox content (string)PROP2 to a property (code behind) and in my HOME i just bind those properties to the propperties in my HomeViewModel

```
 <local:userControl  PROP1="{Binding Text}" PROP2="{Binding Name}" />
```

Now i want to databind the button click with same method , what want todo in my userControl page is

```
<Button Content="Button" Command="{Binding Klick}"/>
```

But i don't know how to store it in property so i can use it later

Here is how i want the final Home something like

```
<local:userControl  Klick="{Binding Commandp}" PROP1="{Binding Textp}" PROP2="{Binding Namep}" />
```

and the HomeViewModel

```
class HomeViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ICommand Commandp{ get; private set; }


    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    public HomeViewModel (IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        Commandp= new DelegateCommand(() => NavigateTo("Docs"));
    }

    private void NavigateTo(string url)
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(Regions.Contentregoin, url);
    }
}
```

PS: I'm using the ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel

Answer (score 1):

That works the same way as `PROP1` and `PROP2` - create a dependency property and you're good to go.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty KlickProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( nameof(Klick), typeof(ICommand), typeof(userControl), new PropertyMetadata( default(ICommand) ) );

public ICommand Klick
{
    get { return (ICommand)GetValue( KlickProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( KlickProperty, value ); }
}
```